# Why is the whitespace missing when loading text into a multiline textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a issue where, when my application downloads a .txt file from my website that contains white spaces etc. When it loads it into the multiline textbox all the white spaces are gone.. How can I get around this?

I've got this code atm:

```
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("xxxxxxxxxx.com/random.txt");
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                textBoxChangeLog.Text = content;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add some sample file.

Comment: Have you looked at the string within a debugger? What sort of whitespace are you using? This should be absolutely fine, although WinForms expects line breaks to be of the form "\r\n"

Comment: Load the file in a RichTextBox, see whether you have like breaks there. The RTB accepts `\n`, `\r\n` and `\r` as line feeds, then transforms everything to `\n`. Maybe your text uses just `\n` as line feed (quite common). If that's the case, you can replace all `\n` with `\r\n` or simply use a RTB instead of a TextBox.

Comment: @JonSkeet
When I open the same file locally, it works just fine. But the text file has some lines separated with ENTER.

Comment: Btw, the RTB control has also a `LoadFile()` method: you can pass it the Stream (specifying `RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText` or `RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText`).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "has some lines separated with ENTER" - but it's almost certainly a line break issue. Save the file you've downloaded in C# (e.g. `File.WriteAllText("result.txt", content);`) and compare that file with the "working" file in a binary file editor so you can see the exact differences.

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean the file looks fine in just plain notepad.. I've written the text file with notepad... Nothing more special than that. And whenever I load that same text file locally with File.ReadAllText it looks like it should... It's just a problem when I am downloading it from the internet. Like I wrote a line in the text file and hit enter a few times and wrote another line etc... But all the white space in between are gone. When the file is being downloaded. But when I open it in the web browser at the same location, it looks as it should.. With the white spaces.

Comment: It is showing \n in the debugger as a line break.

Comment: Problem solved as I didn't see Jimis answer. Thanks!